# Converting Bytes read to seconds read

Tags: c++11, wav, riff

I am reading data from a Riff wav fmt file, I have an array of the data chunk `DataBuffer` of the wav file, how can I convert the number of bytes read of the data to the number of seconds read from the wav file.

```
int size_buffer = (Subchunk2Size / (NumOfChan * bitsPerSample / 8));
FILE* WavResult = fopen(FileNom, "rb");
u8* DataBuffer = new u8[size_buffer];
size_t nRead = fread(DataBuffer, sizeof DataBuffer[0], size_buffer, WavResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up things a bit. Assuming the field names in the WAV header as described in http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat :

```
ChunkID - "RIFF"
ChunkSize
    Format - "WAVE"
    Subchunk1ID - "fmt "
    Subchunk1Size
        AudioFormat
        NumChannels
        SampleRate
        ByteRate
        BlockAlign
        BitsPerSample
    Subchunk2ID - "data"
    Subchunk2Size
        data
```

This line of yours:

```cxx
int size_buffer = (Subchunk2Size / (NumOfChan * bitsPerSample / 8));
```

calculates a number of samples in a single channel. Or a number of blocks, where the block is a structure that contains one sample for each channel. If you use that for allocating memory for *bytes* from `data` chunk, then it will be enough only in case of 8-bit mono audio.

If allocating memory for *bytes* is really what you want, then simply use `Subchunk2Size` as the size.

If you want to allocate memory for *samples*, then it will differ depending if the audio is 8-bit or 16-bit (I'm ignoring other possibilities). For 8-bit:

```cpp
const uint32_t num_of_samples = Subchunk2Size / (BitsPerSample / 8);
uint8_t *samples = new uint8_t[num_of_samples];
```

and for 16-bit:

```cpp
const uint32_t num_of_samples = Subchunk2Size / (BitsPerSample / 8);
int16_t *samples = new int16_t[num_of_samples];
```

Personally, I'd rather use `std::vector` instead of c-arrays:

```cpp
const uint32_t num_of_samples = Subchunk2Size / (BitsPerSample / 8);
std::vector<int16_t> samples;
samples.resize(num_of_samples);    // could be done in the constructor, but I am afraid of vector constructors ;-)
```

I also assume here that the audio is in the most popular encoding (I think), i.e., unsigned for 8-bit and signed for 16-bit. I'm also ignoring the issue of endianness.

---

But back to the number of seconds. We can calculate that using the total number of blocks and `SampleRate`. `SampleRate` tells us how many samples (in a single channel) there are per second. Or in another words, how many blocks there are per second. So the number of seconds is:

```cxx
const double num_of_seconds = 1.0 * num_of_blocks / SampleRate;
```

You can calculate the number of blocks using the formula from your first line:

```cxx
const uint32_t num_of_blocks = Subchunk2Size / (NumChannels * BitsPerSample / 8);
```

or, as we already have `num_of_samples`, which is the total number of samples from all channels, we can just divide that by `NumChannels`:

```cxx
const uint32_t num_of_blocks = num_of_samples / NumChannels;
```

---

And lastly, in case all you wanted was really just to get the number of seconds from the number of *bytes*, then there are 2 options. You can calculate the block size:

```cxx
const int block_size = NumChannels * BitsPerSample / 8;
```

which should be essentially the same as `BlockAlign`, and then divide `Subchunk2Size` by it, to get the number of blocks, and again by `SampleRate` to get the number of seconds:

```cpp
const double num_of_seconds = 1.0 * Subchunk2Size / block_size / SampleRate;
// or
const double num_of_seconds = 1.0 * Subchunk2Size / BlockAlign / SampleRate;
```

Or you can use `ByteRate`, which is the number of bytes per second:

```cxx
const double num_of_seconds = 1.0 * Subchunk2Size / ByteRate;
```